# How to Count the number of times of purchases per customer in a Month?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know how many times a customer bought per month since the store has been opened.

I have this code:

```
SELECT 
    Descrip Customer_Name
    , CodClie ID_Customer
    , CASE WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN Monto
        ELSE -Monto END AS Purchase_Amount$
    , CONVERT(varchar, FechaE, 1) AS Date
    , CodUbic Store_Location
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER ( partition by Descrip order by NumeroD) + 
DENSE_RANK() OVER (partition by Descrip order by NumeroD desc) -1 as Times_bought_since_1st_Day
    
   
FROM 
    dbo.SAFACT
WHERE
    TipoFac IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY  
     FechaE --- Date in timestamp, that's why I converted it
    , CodUbic --- Stores Location
    , Monto --- Amount spent $
    , Descrip --- Customer Name
    , TipoFac --- A for purchases, B for returned products, that why I make the Case Statement
    , CodClie --- ID Customer
    , NumeroD --- NumeroD = Bill
    
ORDER BY YEAR(FechaE) DESC, MONTH(FechaE) DESC, DAY(FechaE) DESC;
```

If I run this code, It will show something like this:

```
Customer_Name ID_Customer Purchase_Amount$    Date     Store_Location Times_bought_since_1st_Day  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Peter Grifin   12345678      1.5           06/14/2022    000-1               10
Ralph Lauren   89101112      2.0           06/14/2022    000-4               15
Meg Stacy      13141516      4.0           06/14/2022    000-5               10
```

The issue here is that I need the times bought but per month, even if It is possible make a group by per every customer's name and their amount spent together with the times bought

The expected result would be something like:

```
 Customer_Name ID_Customer Purchase_Amount$    Date     StoreLocation TimesBoughtSince1stDay TimesBoughtCurrentMonth  TotalSpentSince1stDay    TotalSpentThisMonth
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Peter Grifin   12345678      1.5           06/14/2022    000-1               10                20                      100.000               1.000
    Ralph Lauren   89101112      2.0           06/14/2022    000-4               15                05                      25.000                500.00        
    Meg Stacy      13141516      4.0           06/14/2022    000-5               18                10                      15.000                200.00
```

If there any possibility to split the times bought per month?

Comment: [minimal reproducible example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The link is about asking on dba.stackexchange.

Comment: Why do you have a `GROUP BY` here? You have no aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are confusing because you want to mix calculations within differents times aggregations in one table from the beggining. If you think the problem like 3 different problems and then mixing them, it will be easier.

Try to calculate in different tables by time aggregation and then joining the tables.

The first 5 columns of what you want to achieve are transactional data with an aggregation of days. Every row is a sale made one specific day, a customer can do 1 or more purchases every day.

Then, with the columns TimesBoughtSince1stDay and TotalSpentSince1stDay you don´t need to aggregate by date. You need to aggregate by Customer entire history and you can achieve that by doing:

```
SELECT 
    Descrip Customer_Name
    ,CodClie ID_Customer
    ,sum(CASE WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN Monto ELSE -Monto END) 'Purchase_Amount$'
    , count( DISTINCT NumeroD ) -- here I don´t understand that much your code but you need to count differents SaleId's
FROM dbo.SAFACT
WHERE TipoFac IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY Descrip Customer_Name, CodClie ID_Customer
```

For the month time aggregation you can do someting like:

```
SELECT 
    Descrip Customer_Name
    , CodClie ID_Customer
    , sum(CASE WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN Monto
        ELSE -Monto END) 'Purchase_Amount$'
    , count( DISTINCT NumeroD ) -- here I don´t understand that much your code but you need to count differents SaleId's
FROM 
    dbo.SAFACT
WHERE
    TipoFac IN ('A', 'B')
AND MONTH(CONVERT(DATE,FechaE)) = MONTH(GETDATE())
AND YEAR(CONVERT(DATE,FechaE)) = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY Descrip Customer_Name, CodClie ID_Customer, MONTH(CONVERT(DATE,FechaE))
```

Once you have your 3 differents tables(aggregation by date, aggregation by customer history and aggregation by month) you need to do a left join over the "aggregation by date" table.

Surely some of the code isn´t 100% ready to run but i wanted you to catch the main idea. Hope it will help!